# Error when UI Testing Android Apps using Jetpack Compose, dagger hilt and JUnit4

Tags: android, testing, android-jetpack-compose, dagger, dagger-hilt

I've Issue when UI Testing an android app using Jetpack Compose, dagger hilt and JUnit4.
I'm just want to test tap on my button
here's the detail:

```
@HiltAndroidTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class HomeUITest {
@get:Rule(order = 0)
var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

// use createAndroidComposeRule<YourActivity>() if you need access to
// an activity
@get:Rule(order = 1)
val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

lateinit var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel

@Before
fun setUp() {
    hiltRule.inject()

    composeTestRule.setContent {
        DanamonAppTheme {
            LoginPageScreen()
        }
    }
}

@Test
fun myUIComponentTest() = runTest {

    composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Login").performClick()

}
}
```

when i run the test class, i got error ->

```
Hilt test, com.kelvin.pastisystem.HomeUITest, cannot use a @HiltAndroidApp application 
but found com.kelvinquantic.danamon.MainApplication. To fix, configure the test to use 
HiltTestApplication or a custom Hilt test application generated with 
@CustomTestApplication.
```

i've add @HiltAndroidApp annotation to my Main Application class, just like this ->

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MainApplication : Application() {
...
```

i've tried some solution from blogs and chatGPT but not found good solution, please help. thankyou for your attention

Answer (score 0):

I initialize the viewmodel using this method.
You can use this method to initialize the viewModel.
I hope your problem will be resolved.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class RegisterViewModelTest {
private val registerUseCase: RegisterUseCase = mock()
private val getCountriesUseCase: GetCountriesUseCase = mock()
private val getJobsUseCase: GetJobsUseCase = mock()

@OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
private val mainThreadSurrogate = newSingleThreadContext("UI thread")

@Before
fun setUp() {
    Dispatchers.setMain(mainThreadSurrogate)
}

@After
fun tearDown() {
    Dispatchers.resetMain() // reset the main dispatcher to the original Main 
       dispatcher
    mainThreadSurrogate.close()
}

@Test
fun `onExpertise adds expertise to the list`(): Unit = runBlocking {
    launch {
        val vm: RegisterViewModel = RegisterViewModel(registerUseCase, 
        getCountriesUseCase, getJobsUseCase)
        val expertise = Expertise(id = 1, name = "Test Expertise")

        // When
        vm.onTriggerEvent(RegisterUiEvent.OnExpertise(expertise))

        // Then
        assert(vm.uiState.value.data.expertises?.contains(expertise) == true)
    }
}
```

}